# Is there any way to allow admin to edit the user password in Orchard CMS?

Tags: passwords, admin, orchardcms, edit

Is there an extension i can use to allow the admin to edit the user password in orchard? Because, when i go to Settings>Users>Edit User, i have options only to change the user name, email or roles?

And if no there are no extensions in the gallery, any suggestions how to custom do it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Edit as in view + change a password, or just set a new password?

Comment: I have found a module: Change Password. It allows me(as admin) to change passwords of any user including mine. It works perfect. :)

Comment: You should consider posting that as a self answer to your question.

Comment: There's a feature for that in Orchard 1.9. Nothing to install, it comes standard.

Answer (score 5):

I have used the Change Password module from Gallery. It lets you change passwords to every user and show a new tab in the Users category.